# ActiveX for IE10, windows 8

Tags: c++, bho

I have developed a ActiveX for IE, which get the  information.

System: Windows 8 , IE 10 Desktop version. Account: Administrator

Now there is a problem. The same two html pages, A.html on local machine, B.html on network web server. I used the ActiveX to access them. A.html can get   information, but B.html is NULL like get_document,get_body, all are null.

I had did more test on Windows 7-IE10/IE9/IE8/IE7.  Windows Vista-IE 8/IE7, Windows XP-IE8/IE7/IE6,  all OK.

What's problem on Windows 8 IE 10?